# Accept remote TCP/IP request from aLL IPs in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I have problem with access to SQL server with TCP/IP.

I would like to SQL instance accept client from all network adapter that machine has.

I go to configuration manager console and enable TCP/IP, set TCP port to 1433 (or any other port) , set “TCP Dynamic Port” to Blank and set “Listen All” to true. After these changes, I restart SQL server service and starting SQL service will fail. For starting SQL service I have to change “Listen All” to false and then service will start successfully.

But after  disabling “Listen ALL”  you have to set Adapter IP in “IP Addresses” tab and SQL will accept request only from that IP and if you don’t specify any IP, SQL doesn’t accept any TCP/IP request.

Now I need to know why enabling  “Listen ALL”  will lead to service failure.  And how can I resolve this problem?

I ran “netstate –a” and I saw no application has port 1433 on TCP.

When “Listen ALL”  was disable and I don’t added any specific IP Yet, I check SQL browser service(UDP 1434) with “portquery.exe” and SQL browser response doesn’t include any TCP port.

After I added 1 specific IP  SQL browser service include TCP 1433.

And as I mentioned if I enable “Listen ALL”  , SQL service will failure and after restart it can’t start.

After service restart failure I checked windows event viwer and I saw 4 Error as Following :

1. TDSSNIClient initialization failed with error 0xd, status code 0x10. Reason: Unable to retrieve registry settings from TCP/IP protocol's 'IPAll' configuration key. The data is invalid.
2. TDSSNIClient initialization failed with error 0xd, status code 0x1. Reason: Initialization failed with an infrastructure error. Check for previous errors. The data is invalid.
3. Could not start the network library because of an internal error in the network library. To determine the cause, review the errors immediately preceding this one in the error log.
4. SQL Server could not spawn FRunCommunicationsManager thread. Check the SQL Server error log and the Windows event logs for information about possible related problems.

Finally , How I can Listen to all IPs?

Thanks

this is image of my rgistry IPAll

[image]

Comment: This might be a better fit for [Stack DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com/).  If you agree you can move by clicking  `Flag >> Should be closed... >> Off topic because... >> This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network`.

Comment: there is no one to help me?

Answer (score 0):

[This article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqljourney/2012/06/15/how-a-tiny-little-whitespace-can-make-life-difficult-for-your-sql-cluster/) seems to refer to the same issue. Below the part about how to solve the issue. Maybe it is also the solution to your problem.

> So, the error says the data in the IPAll configuration key is invalid.
>   Where exactly is this key anyways? The TCP protocol, and the IPAll
>   subkey, are located in :
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINESoftwareMicrosoftMicrosoft SQL
>   ServerMSSQLServerSuperSocketNetLib
>
> Under the IPAll subkey, you will find the same two “TCP Dynamic Ports”
>   and “TCP Port” keys. Check the value for the TCP Dynamic Ports key. Do
>   you see a whitespace there? If so, then most likely that is the reason
>   for the service startup failure. Removing the whitespace should fix
>   the issue, and the service should come online just fine.

Comment: hello @DAXaholic . I add image of my registry , I didnt see whitespace that you mentioned, do you see any problem in that?

Comment: Well of course not - it is a whitespace so how should I see it :) You have to double-click the TcpDynamicPorts key so that the edit dialog opens and then when selecting the field's value you can check if there is a space or something like that in it

Comment: dear @Daxaholic unfortunately there is no whitespace

Comment: you dont have any other idea?

Comment: It was just a try as I found that article talking about the same event log entries. I think your question is better suited for Stack DBA.

Comment: I asked my question there , if i get solution I will publish that here. thank you